# JAVA Random.nextInt(int n) returning 0 for n >= 2^16

Tags: java, random, integer

I'm kind of confused. As soon as i is 16 and above mit randomly choosen x is 0. How come?

```
Random random  = new Random();
    for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int[] input = generateArray( (int)Math.round(Math.pow(2, i)), (int)Math.round(Math.pow(2, i+i)) );
        int x = input[random.nextInt(input.length-1)];
        System.out.println(BinarySearch.go(input, x));
    }
```

Sorry, I forgot to show you generateArray:

```
public static int[] generateArray(int amount, int max)
{
    int[] randomNumbers = new int[amount];
    double delta = max / (float)amount;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        randomNumbers[i] = (int)Math.round(i*delta + random.nextDouble() * delta);
    }
    return randomNumbers;
}
```

Basically generates an int array of length amount and fills it with randomly (bound = amount * 2) found increasing integers.

Comment: What does `input` contain?

Comment: What is `generateArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `generateArray` grows exponentially faster then the first `i+i`. At 16 bits, actually 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 you overflow int,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 15; i < 20; i++) {
        long a = Math.round(Math.pow(2, i));
        long b = Math.round(Math.pow(2, i + i));
        int c = (int) b;
        System.out.printf("i = %d, a = %d, b = %d, c = %d%n", i, a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Output is

```
i = 15, a = 32768, b = 1073741824, c = 1073741824
i = 16, a = 65536, b = 4294967296, c = 0
i = 17, a = 131072, b = 17179869184, c = 0
i = 18, a = 262144, b = 68719476736, c = 0
i = 19, a = 524288, b = 274877906944, c = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid me! Was meant to be `i+1` instead `i+i`. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
Math.round(Math.pow(2, i + i))
```

where `i = 16` (similar results if `i` is bigger than 16).

That is `2^32` which, in binary, is representable as

```
<leading 0s>1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

which is a `long`, it can't fit in a `int`. You perform the cast, which discards the leading bits, and get an `int` value of `0`.